# Laravel javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, socket.io

I'm using socket.io for my websockets in laravel. I'm having difficulty in writing API call for my location change method. 
Is there a way to write javascript code in controller of Laravel rather than loading a view and then emitting a socket.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you need to `emit` a message from your server through javascript when you can use `Laravel broadcasting`?

Comment: I'm using 3rd party integrations from SWOOP API need to hit that api first get the response and then emit the response to the receiver

Comment: Okay, but still, that doesn't interfere with how websockets work in any way, you can still make a request to third party API and after the response `emit` the `Event` from `Laravel` using it's `Broadcasting` instead of `injecting javascript and using emit` which is more of a hack than proper way of doing it

Comment: Working on a prebuilt system not free for most changes so It might me easier if there is a way to add js within the controller method